# How do i find deadlock in given diagram?

Tags: operating-system, deadlock

I have given with two Diagrams, one of the diagram says there exist deadlock and other says there in no deadlock. But I could not find how one says there is no deadlock and one says there is deadlock.

Where is the deadlock in the following diagram??

[image]

Comment: What do the pointed arrows mean from Resource --> Process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Have :-
   R1 R2 R3 R4
P1 0  1  0  0
P2 1  1  0  0
P3 0  0  1  0

Need :-
   R1 R2 R3 R4
P1 1  0  0  0
P2 0  0  1  0
P3 0  1  0  0

Available
R1 0
R2 0
R3 0
R4 3
```

You can see that in the current state you cannot complete the request of any process, and processes are waiting for other process to free the resources. Thus, its a deadlock.

Comment: And more thing i would like to ask if edge from p3-> R2 is removed ,then deadlock in not there ,is it true??

Comment: @Amit : Yes. Then p3 doesn't need anymore resources, it finishes and frees up R3. Now, r3 can be allocated to p2, which will then execute and free up its locked resources. Now, resources can be allocated to p1, which will then execute and free up all the resources.

Answer (score 0):

Arrows completing a full cycle forms deadlock. In this case R2-P2-R3-P3-R2 is a complete cycle. so deadlock may occur.

Comment: Its a complete cycle and deadlock may occur is fine but what is the ultimate condition for deadlock to happen.I have seen the situation where there is complete cycle but deadlock does not occur

Answer (score 0):

Every process is requesting a resource and holding its own resource as well, it satisfies the conditions of mutual exclusion, no preemption, hold and wait and circular wait condition of deadlock as well so it is a deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

@Amit singh toamr..i think you are probably asking about the condition when it make a cycle with just two processes..well i have seen that there P2 and P4 are not requesting any resource so i do not make a cycle and for a deadlock to occur it must be a cycle. Hope it help.